# Is it possible to selectively retract during F5-debug re-deployment?

Tags: solution-deployment, debugging, testing

Is there anyway I can select certain project features to remain deployed instead of being overwritten each time I F5-debug-deploy? ...other than creating multiple Solutions.

If not, are there suggestions for speeding up my code-test cycle?
I have a very large SharePoint project that is slow to deploy/activate.
My test cases involve Document Sets containing sequential same name document versions, so the complexity of the test setup rules out `<element><data>`
My Snap-In is failing so can't use PowerShell ([see here if you have answer for that one](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/97953/snapin-wont-load-the-cmdlets-now-target-the-wrong-powershell-version-howd-th))

Ideally, I just want to spare my testing setups from needless destruction each time I re-deploy (columns/content-types/list-defentions don't change - just my code-behind)
Perhaps there is some Visual Studio project feature inclusion/exclusion trickery I could employ to avoid the tedium?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to replace the assemblies, you can compile These and copy it to the GAC manually. Refresh the Application pool in IIS and attach the debugger to the w3c Processing.

This is a very ugly solution, but it can help to minimize the deployment erfort.

Edit:

Here it is http://spsd.codeplex.com/

Comment: At the Moment i did Not have my pc online. Tomorrow I can send you a Tool that also Support quick and partial deployments out of Visual studio.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to evaluate the partial deployment tool.  That may be the solution.  Thanx

Comment: And There it is :)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but this looks a little "heavy" for what I wanted to accomplish.  I'll keep checking back tough - this looks promising (from SPSD website)


_In the future, SPSD will provide a Visual Studio project template which can be added to your existing Visual Studio SharePoint project and recreates the deployment package on every build. Currently only the scripts are available which can be used independently._